# Using AND in query causes the query to return everything

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query

I am attempting to return all records by a certain User by Today, Yesterday and Last Week.

In each case, the query returns all records instead of the correct data.

I use Today OffsetDays='-1' and Today OffsetDays='-7'

```
    public static List<Business.Entities.api.newsalert> Yesterday(int Limit, string findme)
    {
        Business.Utility.loadConfigurations();
        Uri uri = new Uri(SharePointConnector.sp_site_address);

        using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(uri))
        {
            //Configure the handler that will add the header.
            clientContext.ExecutingWebRequest += new EventHandler<WebRequestEventArgs>(clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest);

            NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(string.Format("{0}\\{1}", SharePointConnector.sp_domain, SharePointConnector.sp_site_username), SharePointConnector.sp_site_pwd);
            CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
            cc.Add(uri, "NTLM", nc);
            clientContext.Credentials = cc;
            clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;

            // Assume the web has a list named "ADMPANewsAlertsWebAPI". 
            List announcementsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(SharePointConnector.sp_NewsAlerts_list);

            // This creates a CamlQuery that has a RowLimit of 100, and also specifies Scope="RecursiveAll" 
            // so that it grabs all list items, regardless of the folder they are in.                 
            CamlQuery CamlQuery = new CamlQuery();

            string qs;
            if (findme != null)
            {
                qs = String.Format(
                            "<View>" +
                            "<Query>" +
                            "<Where>" +
                            "<And>" +
                            "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Author_x003a_ID'/><Value Type='Lookup'>{0}</Value></Eq>" +
                            "<Leq><FieldRef Name='Created'/><Value Type='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='-1'/></Value></Leq>" +
                            "</And>" +
                            "</Where>" +
                            "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" Ascending =\"False\"/></OrderBy></Query>" +
                            "</Query>", findme
                            );
            }
            else
            {
                qs = String.Format(
                            "<View>" +
                            "<Query>" +
                            "<Where>" +
                            "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Created'/><Value Type='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='-1'/></Value></Eq>" +
                            "</Where>" +
                            "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" Ascending =\"False\"/></OrderBy></Query>" +
                            "</Query>"
                            );
            }

            CamlQuery.ViewXml = qs;

            ListItemCollection items = announcementsList.GetItems(CamlQuery);

            // Retrieve all items in the ListItemCollection from List.GetItems(Query). 
            clientContext.Load(items);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            var list = new List<Business.Entities.api.newsalert>();
            foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
            {
                var foo = new Business.Entities.api.newsalert();

                //Build obj here
                list.Add(foo);
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
```

*****Updated Query that now Returns Cannot complete this action  ******

```
                            "<View>" +
                            "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" Ascending =\"False\"/></OrderBy>" +
                            "<Query>" +
                            "<Where>" +
                            "<And>" +
                            "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Author_x003a_ID'/><Value Type='Lookup'>{0}</Value></Eq>" +
                            "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Created'/><Value Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value></Eq>" +
                            "</And>" +
                            "</Where>" +
                            "</Query>" +
                            "<View>", findme
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you're adding the query above to your query to SharePoint?

Comment: I've updated my code - thx

Answer (score 1):

Both of your CAML queries appear to be missing the closing  tag, which will render the CAML invalid causing it to just return everything.

Comment: I've updated my code but it nows says -  Cannot complete this action

Comment: @Tim Cadieux You also double close `<Query>`

Comment: I updated my original code with the updated query which now fails

Comment: Can you add your updated CAML string to the comments here? (doesn't have to be the code, can just be the qs string directly.

Comment: This is what fails -
qs = "<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author_x003a_ID'/><Value Type='Lookup'>18</Value></Eq><Leq><FieldRef Name='Created'/><Value Type='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='-1'/></Value></Leq></And></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" Ascending =\"False\"/></OrderBy></Query></View>"

Comment: I don't think you need to add the `<View></View>` portions, but it's been a while

Comment: For consistency (and just to rule it out an escape character issue) Remove \" and just use '. Is it failing on the setting of the viewxml or on executequery? What's the error?